# Unknown property 'Fishing_Session__cStandardController.Action'

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to use URLFOR but my VF page does not compile.

This is my code :

```
<apex:page standardController="Fishing_Session__c" showHeader="true" >
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR(Action.Account.New)}">New Account</apex:outputLink>
</apex:page>
```

Error message :
Unknown property 'Fishing_Session__cStandardController.Action'

Answer (score 1):

It's [$Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_action.htm), not Action.

```
<apex:page standardController="Fishing_Session__c" showHeader="true" >
  <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.New)}" >
    New Account
  </apex:outputLink>
</apex:page>
```